# quick StringOutOfBoundsException inquiry

Tags: java, exception

```
            if(Character.isDigit(character) && Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(x+1)))
            {
                output += character;
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(character))
            {
                output += character + " ";
            }   
            else
            {
                output += character;
            }
```

This code block is in a much larger for loop which is traversing through a string. 
The x+1 causes a StringOutOfBoundsException, is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Yes: don't call charAt(x+1) if x == expression.length() - 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an extra check that the value of `x + 1` is less than the length of the string to ensure you don't index past the end of the string:

```
if (Character.isDigit(character) &&
    (x + 1) < expression.length &&
    Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(x+1)))
```